# Copy Contacts from Blackberry Touch to Galaxy S3 without google sync

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, blackberry

Just came across a problem when switching from Blackberry Touch to the Galaxy S3. How can I automatically move the contacts from the old device to the new one without typing it myself? Some one suggested me using Google sync but the problem is that Google services are blocked in my country. Anyone has other solution to fix the problem? Thx